# Order query result by latest updated date

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on two tables,

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `usernick` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `usernick_UNIQUE` (`usernick` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `messageid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `sendid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `recid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `message` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`messageid`) ,
  INDEX `sender_fk_idx` (`sendid` ASC) ,
  INDEX `reciever_fk_idx` (`recid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `sender_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sendid` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `reciever_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`recid` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and want a list of user on basis if their last sent message. Eg.

```
select U.fname,U.lname,U.usernick from messages as M natural join users as U where M.sendid = U.userid and M.recid={$_SESSION['user_id']} group by U.usernick ORDER BY M.date DESC
```

EXAMPLE:

```
name         msg sent to "RON" on

Alpha        17 aug
Beta         18 aug
Alpha        19 aug
Gamma        20 aug


SO i want a list like, 

gamma (last msg on 20)
alpha (last msg on 18)
beta  (last msg on 19)
```

SEE LINK http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dca2/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it.  You just need `max(m.date)` in the `order by` clause.  Otherwise, an arbitrary date is chosen:

```
select U.fname,U.lname,U.usernick
from messages as M join
     users as U
      on M.sendid = U.userid
where M.recid={$_SESSION['user_id']}
group by U.usernick
ORDER BY max(M.date) DESC
```

I also fixed the `join` syntax.  It is best to avoid natural joins -- that is, be explicit about the join condition.  You do this *anyway*, so I switched the condition to an `on` clause and the `natural join` to a `join`.